# Pointer with a pointer constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, initialization

In C++, how can I achieve the following:

```
// player.h
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
class Player {
    public:
        Player(Cake* cake);
}
#endif

// player.cpp
#include "cake.h"
#include "player.h"
Player::Player(Cake* cake) { }

// cake.h
#ifndef CAKE_H
#define CAKE_H
class Cake {
    public:
        Cake( );
}
#endif

// cake.cpp
#include "cake.h"
Cake::Cake() { }

// main.cpp
#include "player.h"
#include "cake.h"
int main() {
    Cake* cake();
    Player* player(cake); // This does not work

    return 0;
}
```

In other words, Have a `Player` pointer that takes a `Cake` pointer in it's constructor.

However, when I try compiling the application with `g++` i get the following error:
`error: cannot convert ‘Cake* (*)()’ to ‘Player*’ in initialization`.

It probably makes sense, but I'd like to know why I can't have **a pointer that takes a pointer (in the constructor)**.

Comment: What's wrong with automatic variables? `Cake cake; Player player(cake);` is much easier and better.

Comment: This is just a dummy application I made, the "real" application looks a bit different. I had some problems with inheritance when I did not use pointers (e.g virtual functions in the parent class seemed to get called every time when the purpose was to call a child class' inherited function.

Comment: Oh my. That sounds bad. You might want to get yourself [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a mistaken local initialization.

```
Cake* cake();
Player* player(cake);
```

needs to be rewritten to

```
Cake* cake = new Cake();
Player* player = new Player(cake);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Cake* cake();
```

Here `cake` is not a variable as you might assume. Compiler looks as if `cake()` is a forward declaration which returns `Cake*` and takes no argument.

It can be,

```
Cake cake;
Player *player = new Player(&cake);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper C++ syntax:

```
Cake* cake = new Cake();
Player* player = new Player(cake);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cake is an unknown type in player.h . Use a forward declaration:

```
// player.h

class Cake;

class Player
{
  private:
    Cake* m_cake;
  public:
    Player( Cake* c ) : m_cake(c) {}
};
```